# No Result Set for SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problem with the invocation an SQL query
After I invoke the SQL query, the result is empty.

**SQLAdapter-impl.js**

```
//Create SQL query
var getAccountsTransactionsStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement(
"SELECT transactionId, fromAccount, toAccount, transactionDate,        transactionAmount, transactionType " +
"FROM accounttransactions " +
"WHERE accounttransactions.fromAccount = ? OR accounttransactions.toAccount    = ? " +
"ORDER BY transactionDate DESC " +
"LIMIT 20;"
);

//Invoke prepared SQL query and return invocation result    
function getAccountTransactions1(accountId){
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : getAccountsTransactionsStatement,
    parameters : [accountId, accountId]
});
}

//Invoke stored SQL procedure and return invocation result
function getAccountTransactions2(accountId){
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
    procedure : "getAccountTransactions",
    parameters : [accountId]
});
}
```

**Invocation Result:**

```
{
   isSuccessful: true,
   resultSet: [ ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: does the above query give you result in the sql database.

Comment: the result is exactly like what I've shown above
{
   isSuccessful: true,
   resultSet: [ ]
}

Comment: Then obviously it's a problem with your query and not the adapters...

Comment: I'm following the tutorial exactly like this link https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/sql-adapter-communicating-sql-database/

Comment: @user3402438 no i am asking when u give the query " SELECT transactionId, fromAccount, toAccount, transactionDate,        transactionAmount, transactionType FROM accounttransactions WHERE accounttransactions.fromAccount = (somevalue) OR accounttransactions.toAccount    = (somevalue) ORDER BY transactionDate DESC LIMIT 20; " in the sql command promt do you get the result as u wanted.

Comment: did you passed 12345 as account id for parameters ?

Comment: @Kawinesh SK Even if put the value inside (somevalue), for example, accounttransactions.fromAccount = (12345) OR accounttransactions.toAccount = (12345) , I can get the result in sql command but cannot get result in JSON format that are displayed in browser

Answer (score 0):

```
var getAccountsTransactionsStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("SELECT transactionId, fromAccount, toAccount, transactionDate,     transactionAmount, transactionType FROM accounttransactions WHERE accounttransactions.fromAccount = ? OR accounttransactions.toAccount    = ? ORDER BY transactionDate DESC LIMIT 20");
```

> 1. Execute the above line don't use `+""` as a line joiners in the java
>      script.
> 2. Try to give the command in the single line as above and say me
>      the result.
> 3. And to be safe remove the `;` at the end of the sql query.